# HDMI connections does not work

Tags: hdmi, external-monitor

I got Ubuntu 20.04 and my computer does not detect the external monitor connected via HDMI

Why is this?

Comment: Does `sudo journalctl  -b 0 | grep HDMI` show anything? Watch `sudo journalctl -f` as you unplug and replug the cable, with the monitor ON.

Comment: What are your laptop specifications? Do you have any gpus e.g nvidia or amd etc. Please update your question with the outputs of the commands `xrandr ` and `sudo journalctl -b 0 | grep HDMI`